# Ler chave do JSON com Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Estou com uma dificuldade ao tentar ler o valor de uma **chave** específica do meu `JSON`.

Tenho o seguinte JSON que está armazenado em meu `LocalStorage`:

```
{idCmos: "83903", codigoPlang: "302432", tipoPlang: "39ieej", nome: "TaskControl"}
```

Estou armazenando em uma variável, conforme abaixo:

```
  var dados_usuario = localStorage.getItem('dados_usuario');
```

Quando tento ler o valor da chave `nome` via `alert()`, está retornando a mensagem **undefined**.

Segue abaixo meu `alert`:

```
alert (dados_usuario.nomeEntidade);
```

Comment: Mas você quer ler **a chave** ou o **valor referente a uma chave**?

Comment: O valor da chave

Comment: Corrigi a pergunta

Comment: Nesse caso, vc vai ter que postar o JSON. Roda um `console.log(dados_usuario)` e posta o resultado na sua pergunta.

Comment: Coloquei o resultado do console.log

Comment: Tente a dica das respostas abaixo e lembre-se de corrigir "a chave": `dados_usuario.nomeEntidade` para `dados_usuario.nome`. ;d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O localStorage não consegue armazenar objetos, objetos são referências, e referências não são compartilhadas entre contextos diferentes. Uma vez que você fechar a página, ou abrir uma tab, essa referência não irá conseguir acessar o objeto, pois ele não existe em seu contexto.

O que você pode fazer é transformar o Json numa string, e depois decodifica-lo de volta, usando `JSON.stringify` e `JSON.parse`. Exemplo:

```
const dados = {idCmos: "83903", codigoPlang: "302432", tipoPlang: "39ieej", nome: "TaskControl"};
localStorage.setItem('dados', JSON.stringify(dados));
```

---

```
const dados = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dados'));
console.log(dados.idCmos);
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 2):

O localStorage salva uma `string` então para salvar você deve fazer o seguinte:

```
localStorage.setItem('dados_usuario', JSON.stringify(dados_usuario ));
```

E para ler:

```
const dados_usuario = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dados_usuario'));
```

Você pode testar com o código a seguir:

```
const gravar = { idCmos: "83903", codigoPlang: "302432", tipoPlang: "39ieej", nome: "TaskControl" };

// Grava a variável no localStorage
localStorage.setItem('dados_usuario', JSON.stringify(gravar));
// Lê do localStorage
const lido = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dados_usuario'));

console.log(lido.nome);
```

---

> [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage)
>
> A interface de Armazenamento da Web Storage API fornece acesso ao armazenamento de sessão ou armazenamento local para um domínio específico, permitindo que você, por exemplo, adicione, modifique ou exclua itens de dados armazenados.

---

> [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage)
>
> A propriedade localStorage permite acessar um objeto Storage local. A [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage)é similar ao [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). A única diferença é que enquanto os dados armazenados no [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage)não expiram, os dados no sessionStorage tem os seus dados limpos ao expirar a sessão da página — ou seja, quando a página (aba ou janela) é fechada.

---

> [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
>
> A propriedade sessionStorage permite acessar um objeto tipo session Storage. A [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)é similar ao [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage), a única diferença é que enquanto os dados armazenados no [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage)não expiram, os dados no [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) tem os seus dados limpos ao expirar a sessão da página. A sessão da página dura enquanto o browser está aberto e se mantém no recarregamento da página. Abrir a página em uma nova aba ou nova janela, irá gerar uma nova sessão, o que diferencia de como os cookies trabalham.

---

> [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
>
> O método `JSON.parse()` analisa uma string JSON, construindo o valor ou um objeto `JavaScript` descrito pela `string`. Uma função reviver opcional pode ser fornecida para executar uma transformação no objeto resultante antes de ser retornada.

---

> [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
>
> O método `JSON.stringify()` converte valores em `JavaScript` para uma `String`  `JSON`. Esses valores podem ser substituidos especificando a função `replacer`, ou incluindo somente as propriedades específicas, quando o array do `replacer` for especificado.

Comment: Amigo, funcionou. Muito obrigado!!!!